# Recording overlay over the live video iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image

I am trying to record an overlay to the live video feed from the device camera.

I could only find the solution of merging an image or text with recorder video. i.e after the video has been recorded.

What I intend to do is, record the overlay as a part of the video.

The "AVMutableComposition" is also for adding/mixing multiple video and audio assets together and saving them as one asset.

The below code adds sublayer over the video preview:

```
 // 1 - set up the overlay
  CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
  UIImage *overlayImage = nil;
  if (_frameSelectSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame-1.png"];
  } else if(_frameSelectSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame-2.png"];
  } else if(_frameSelectSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame-3.png"];
  }

  [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
  overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

  // 2 - set up the parent layer
  CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
  CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
  parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
  [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

  // 3 - apply magic
  composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                               videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also looking how to do this.

Comment: no recording over live video is 2 much work. i faked it by adding an image layer over the recording screen and then added the overlay

Comment: Same issue for me,is there any option?

Comment: nope no option you have to fake it while recording and then add the layer of image or text to the video layer..

Comment: I was thinking about this, because I am building a similar application. If you have the logic in place to display the text and know when to overlay on the video recording, you would use the same logic after the video is recorded to hard embed the text into the video at the same timestamps that were determined for display..